# jquery ui slider locate next array when clicked on the track

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array

```
valmap = [5,4,3,2,1,0,1,2,3,4,5];
```

Now for example the handle of the slider is on track array[5] which is 0, handle is on the center of the track. When I click on the track array[0] which is 5 the handle should only move to track array[4] which is 1 and not go directly to the end of the track which is array[0] or equals to 5.

It should locate the nearest array. e.g handle is on array[5] is center which have a value of 0. When click on the left track it should find the nearest array and that should be array[4] which have a value of 1.

Again when I click on the track, Now I will click on the right side of the track the handle should move back to array[5] which is the center of the slider which is equal to 0.

How can I do that?

Here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var valMap = [5,4,3,2,1,0,1,2,3,4,5]; //0 is the default camera zoom
    var slider = $( "#slider" ).slider({
      disabled: false,
      animate: true,
      min: 0,
      max: valMap.length-1,
      values: [5],
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#zomlevel" ).val(valMap[ui.values[0]] + "x");
        slider.slider("option", "animate", "slow");        
      }
    });
});
```

Here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/endl3ss/jNwww/

EDIT ADDED EXPLANATION:

For example I click on the left side of the track and the handle is on the center, the handle should not jump directly to the left side of the track where I click the mouse, it should look for the next array and move there instead of jumping to the end of the array.

Comment: the part where u explain about the nature of events to occur on clicks is confusing, would you elaborate a little bit more

Comment: I've edited my post, hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this out.. got it finally ..

Hope this is what you are looking for..

```
$(function() {
    var prevValue=100;
    $( "#slider" ).slider({
        value:100,
        min: 0,
        max: 500,
        step: 50,
        slide: function( event, ui ) {

            if (prevValue>ui.value){
                ui.value= prevValue-50;
            }else{
                ui.value= prevValue+50;
            }
            prevValue=ui.value;

            $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.value );
            $( "#slider" ).slider( "option", "value", prevValue );
            $('#slider').trigger(e);
            }
    });


    $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider" ).slider( "value" ) );
});
```

Comment: Thanks it works great, but when i try to add animate it does not work anymore?

Comment: I'm having problem on this part $('#slider').trigger(e); I'm getting undefined variable e.